# EventBus.$on doesn't seem to catch the event being emitted. (Vue js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

Currently trying to emit an event from router.beforeEach and trying to listen on it in my other component.
However while the vue devtool shows that the event is in fact being emitted, my component cannot seem to catch it.
Thank you in advance.

my EventBus declaration:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
export const EventBus = new Vue()
```

firing the event:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
            console.log('from',from.name,'to',to.name)
            window.axios.get(checkTokenUrl, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('JWT')}`
                }
            }).then(res => res.data)
                .then(data => {
                    next()
                    if(data === true) {
                        console.log('User is Logged in')
                        EventBus.$emit('Logged-in')
                    }else {
                        console.log('User is Logged out')
                        EventBus.$emit('Logged-Out')
                    }
                })
        
        })
```

catching the event:

```
EventBus.$on('Logged-Out',() => {
                this.isUserLoggedIn = false
                localStorage.setItem('JWT', '')
            })

            EventBus.$on('Logged-in',() => {
                this.isUserLoggedIn = true
            })
```

Comment: I think the other component should be a parent/ancestor route of the component you are navigating from, is that the case?

Comment: That was the case, thank you very much.But is there any other way I can use to communicate between different components in vue's navigation guard

Comment: You can use the vue store and watch changes in the store

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I Mixed up the orders in which the listener and the emitter were being created ,and The listener was being created after the emitter and that caused the problem.